# Handle response return from model in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel. I have getting some problem after getting data from database table. I want to know how to handle response after getting result from query in model and return to controller. **Because it returns count value 1 even there is no matching record in database table. If I print count in model it prints 0. but if I print count in controller it prints 1.**

**Model Code**

```
return $data = DB::select(DB::raw("select  us.oid, us.loggedIn, us.sid from user_sessions us where us.user_type = '" . $user_type . "'"));
```

**Controller code**

```
$response = Customer::SessionDetail($user_type);
if(count($response) > 0){
    //do code
}else{
    //no record
}
```

Response :

If we have matching record in mysql table. it works fine.

**Problem** :

When there is no matching record in database table. it will print response message like this.

```
Like:-
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder Object ( [query:protected] => Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Object ( [connection] =>
```

I will cut the message because it will show db connection information on browser.

Comment: Please have a look at Laravel Eloquent. You find a very good tutorial about Laravel at [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
return $data = DB::select("select  us.oid, us.loggedIn, us.sid from user_sessions us where us.user_type = '" . $user_type . "'");
```

Comment: Thanks, Same issue. No luck

Comment: shouldn't it be: user_session as us ?